# The background for my custom view will not change from black

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

My problem is that the joystick that I made using the Canvas class has an automatic black background which I am unable to change. I would like it to be completely transparent.
[This is a picture of the gamescreen and the joystick has an unwanted black rectangle around it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOHlX.png)

This is where the joystick actually gets drawn. I do not draw the background color as black. The "myCanvas.drawColor(Color.Transparent, porterDuff.Mode.ClEAR" just makes it so the image of the ball is deleted when it moves

```
private void drawJoystick(float newX, float newY)
{
    if(getHolder().getSurface().isValid())
    {
        Canvas myCanvas = this.getHolder().lockCanvas(); //Stuff to draw
        Paint colors = new Paint();
        myCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); //Clear the background
        myCanvas.drawARGB(0, 255, 255, 255);
        colors.setARGB(255, 50, 50, 50); //Joystick base color
        myCanvas.drawCircle(xPOS, yPOS, baseRadius, colors);
        colors.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 255); // Color of joystick
        myCanvas.drawCircle(newX, newY, hatRadius, colors); //Draw the hat
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(myCanvas); //Write to surface
    }
```

}

This next section is where the joystick is actually added into the XML file.

```
<yt_7_11.theceaselesssaga.JoystickView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/joystick"
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```